# The Liskov substitution principle

Tags: python, oop, liskov-substitution-principle

I'm reading the book "Learning Python Design Patterns" written by Chetan Giridhar
and I came across a design principle called the Liskov substitution principle, which states
that derived classes must be able to completely substitute the base (parent) class.

I don't think I understand this, because what's the point of writing a derived class
if it can completely replace the base class? Doesn't it make the base class redundant?

From my understanding and experience derived classes extend functionality of the base class hence should be dependent on the base class.

What the author is trying to help me understand?

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51883363/is-this-correct-understanding-of-liskov-substitution-principle

Comment: The thing is, derived classes may be used in any place base class was used. With inheritance, you may still override inherited methods with your own code. This rule basically states that your overridden methods should still behave in expected manner and not do completely different things - so that when you use your derived class instance in place where base class is expected (because derived class instance is still instance of the base class), it works as expected.

Comment: If I understand this correctly what the author meant is that derived classes shouldn't change functionality of inherited method from the base class. That makes sense to me because if you replace the base class with a such class other derived classes will break. Plus, you can always decorate the method in question. Decorators alter how method behaves.

Comment: "Replace" here just means that the subclass should mimic the API of the baseclass, making a subclass instance work wherever a baseclass object is expected. But the subclass can nevertheless add other or modify existing behavior, making it different from the base and therefore non-redundant.

Answer (score 1):

`Derived` classes should extend without replacing the `functionality` of old classes. Which means derived classes should be substitutable for their `parent/base` classes. Moreover, they can be usable in the place of their parent classes without any unexpected behavior.

We can't replace the `parent class's` functionality but we can `re-write` it in the child class and for modification `extend` that child class onwards. It will keep us from the `chain reaction` that might occur in complex software by changing the parent class so we opt to `duplicate` it in child class and then `write` our desired `modifications`.